# Python: is there a faster alternative to using numpy's polyfromroots?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scientific-computing

Using Python, I am looping over a large collection of sets of roots (represented as a 2-dimensional numpy array, essentially), and forming each time the monic polynomial having the set of roots (called roots) as roots, as such:

```
poly = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots(roots)
```

However, my code runs slowly when the number of sets of roots is large (about 40000), even though each set of roots is itself small (containing only 4 roots).

As an example, if I run

```
import timeit

SETUP_CODE = '''
import numpy as np'''

TEST_CODE = '''
N, n = 40000, 4
collection_roots = np.random.random((N,n)) + 1.j*np.random.random((N,n))
polynomials = np.zeros((N, n + 1), dtype=complex)
for k in range(N):
    roots = collection_roots[k, :]
    polynomials[k, :] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots(roots)'''

print(timeit.timeit(setup=SETUP_CODE,
                    stmt=TEST_CODE,
                    number=1))
```

the output on my relatively old machine is about 2.9 seconds. Is there a way to speed up this piece of code, within Python?

There are other places in my code that could use some optimization. Of course, I could create separate posts, but it would help me (and others) if someone could also post some resources they found useful for optimizing Python code for scientific computing.

Comment: Typically in `numpy` we gain speed by working with the whole 2d array of `collection_roots`.  But `polyfromroots` only works with a 1d, and the code is too involved to readily suggest a generalization.  You may have to go back to your polynomial math class, and come with your own version,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy can precalculate the general formula for a given number of roots:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, Product, poly, lambdify

num_roots = 4
x = Symbol('x')
roots = [Symbol(f'r{i}') for i in range(num_roots)]
prod = 1
for ri in roots:
    prod *= (x - ri)
print(prod)
print(poly(prod, x).all_coeffs()[::-1])
np_poly_4_roots = lambdify(roots, poly(prod, x).all_coeffs()[::-1])

np_poly_4_roots(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Calling `help(np_poly_4_roots)` shows its source code:

```
def _lambdifygenerated(r0, r1, r2, r3):
    return ([r0*r1*r2*r3,
             -r0*r1*r2 - r0*r1*r3 - r0*r2*r3 - r1*r2*r3,
             r0*r1 + r0*r2 + r0*r3 + r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r3,
             -r0 - r1 - r2 - r3,
             1])
```

This already works a bit faster, but isn't fully vectorized. But you could use this source to manually create a vectorized version:

```py
def fast_poly_4_roots(r):
    r0, r1, r2, r3 = r[:, 0], r[:, 1], r[:, 2], r[:, 3]
    return np.array([r0 * r1 * r2 * r3,
                     -r0 * r1 * r2 - r0 * r1 * r3 - r0 * r2 * r3 - r1 * r2 * r3,
                     r0 * r1 + r0 * r2 + r0 * r3 + r1 * r2 + r1 * r3 + r2 * r3,
                     -r0 - r1 - r2 - r3,
                     np.ones_like(r0)])
```

For an input with all 4 roots, this can be executed in a vectorized way:

```
N, n = 4000, 4
collection_roots = np.random.random((N,n)) + 1.j*np.random.random((N,n))

polynomials = fast_poly_4_roots(collection_roots)
```

As now there aren't Python for-loops anymore, things are really fast.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out soon!

Comment: While the code in my OP took about 2.8 seconds, using the vectorized version fast_poly_4_roots took only about 0.0065 seconds, so it is about 430 times faster!

Comment: I have a feeling that numpy operations use some kind of parallel procesing of sorts... For example, when they pointwise multiply 2 arrays, they might do many of them in parallel, since they are independent operations, am I right? In any case, thank you so much!

Comment: Numpy is mainly strongly optimized machine code, while standard Python is interpreted. Modern processors, and especially graphics boards, can do calculations on entire arrays in one step, while if you'd use a `for` loop, the process preparation takes up most of the time.

Comment: Another question please. In my code, $n$ itself may vary. Is it possible to get from the lambdifygenerated code to the fully vectorized one programmatically? It does seem doable. Just a hint as to how to do it would be enough.

Comment: Never mind, I think one could just consider the polynomial minus 1, lambdify it, convert it to a numpy array, and then add a column of 1s to the output. Ok, good!

Comment: I think the process has to be repeated for each of `num_roots`. And different arrays `collection_roots` are needed for each of the lengths.

Comment: by the way, I found another method which works about as fast it seems than your method for large $N$ (and possibly faster for small $N$s). I did that using a single loop over the arrays of roots (since in my problem the number of roots is usually small while the number $N$ of sets of roots could be quite large), by multiplying each time, and successively, by a linear factor corresponding to each given root array. The latter operation is easy to write down in vectorized format. It is based on your idea, and works great in practice, so thank you!